# Почему не выводится ключ массива?

Tags: php

Есть код:

```
$fruits = array('sweet' => 'bug', 'sour' => array('ok1' => 'my', 'ok2' => 'your'));

function test_print($item, $key)
{
    echo "$key содержит $item\n";
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
```

Ответ:

```
sweet содержит bug 
ok1 содержит my 
ok2 содержит your
```

Проблема в том, что не выводится название ключа, если внутри него ещё массив, в данном примере ключ sour не был выведен на экран. Как это исправить?

Comment: это нормальное поведение функции `array_walk_recursive()`, в доке об этом сказано. Если вам нужны все ключи массива не определённой глубины, пишите свою рекурсивную функцию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё вариант - эта функция распечатает массив ввиде дерева, а ключи массива, значение которого будет содержать массив, будут обозначены типом *(array)*:

```
<?php

$fruits = array(
    'sweet' => 'bug',
    'sour' => array(
        'ok1'=> 'my',
        'ok2'=> 'your',
        'ok3'=> array(
            'ok1'=> 'my',
            'ok2'=> 'your'
        )
    )
);

echo tree($fruits);


function tree($array, $tab = '', $result = '') {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result .= "{$tab}[$key] <i style='color:red;'>(array)</i><br>";
            $result .= tree($value, $tab . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 4));
        } else {
            $result .= "{$tab}[$key] => <b>$value</b><br>";
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку в документации [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-walk-recursive.php) сказано:

> *Обратите внимание, что ключ `sweet` никогда не отображается. Любой
>   ключ, содержащий значение типа `array`, не будет передаваться в функцию.*

По-этому, пишем свой рекурсивной метод:

```
$fruits = array('sweet' => 'bug', 'sour' => array('ok1' => 'my', 'ok2' => 'your'));

function recursive($array) 
{
    // Для каждого элемента
    foreach($array as $key => $value) 
    {
        if (is_array($value)){
            // Если значение это массив ...
            echo $key . ' содержит ' . $value . '\n';
            recursive($value);
        } else {
            // Если это не массив ...
            echo $key . ' содержит ' . $value . '\n';
        }
    }
}
recursive($fruits);
```

*Результат:*

```
sweet содержит bug
sour содержит Array
ok1 содержит my
ok2 содержит your
```